# How to delete import that is not needed to react native in all files automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I made a project, but I found a lot of imports that are useless and I want to delete them automatically

I tried using a linter but it wasn't automatic

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
```

I want to optimize the import automatically react native as in the android studio

Comment: This is more a Code Editor question not a javascript, reactjs, react native, etc, Remove those tags, and be more specific on the editor you are using.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: i think depending on your IDE it might have a "quick fix" thing, vscode does

Comment: Yes, I using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idk which IDE you are using but for Visual Studio Code which is most popular atm there's a simple rule.

```js
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example or URL ?.

Comment: URL to what? If you are using visual studio code paste this piece of code in settings and on save vsc will do work for you :)

Comment: I am very grateful. Thanks.